# About the ways that install Create React App project with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

A book I got a year ago said...

```
npx create-react-app XXX --typescript
```

Current CRA Docs is saying...

```
npx create-react-app XXX --template typescript
```

Each result seemed the same.
Something different or the former is just shortened way?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--typescript` option has been deprecated. So use the `--template`

Comment: I understood. Thank you!